# Reference between projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have a solution that has 2 projects (Project1 & Project2) and 1 DLL (MyDLL).
I want to know if it's possible to reference MyDLL in Project2 and reference Project2 in Project1 and from Project1 access MyDLL. If it's possible, how i do this?

P.S: I work in visual studio 2013.

**EDIT**

I have to reference this DLL from Project2 in Project1. There is a viable way to do that or if this is a bad idea.. Thanks..

Comment: It sounds like a bad idea, and you haven't indicated _why_ you don't want to reference the DLL.  What's wrong with referencing in directly?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add a reference to MyDLL in Project 1 if you want to use it directly.  The DLL will be included in the build output via the reference in Project 2 but you cannot use it directly without referencing it.

If there's a reason that you don't *want* to reference it directly then add it to your question.

Comment: I need to now if has a way to do that, because in my work solution has 24-25 projects and someone of then has a reference to one dll. Because of this, i think this question and post here... I will edit the post...

Comment: You could try goofy things like loading the assembly in code and accessing everything through reflection or dynamic, but if you want type-safe compile-time access then you'll need to reference the DLL.  What problems does referencing the DLL give you?  Or do you just not want to?